# Segmentation fault after linking Rust staticlib with C

Tags: c, rust, static-linking

I'm trying to link statically against library written in Rust:

```
#![crate_type = "staticlib"]

#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn foo() {
    println!("bork!");
}
```

Using following code in C:

```
void foo();
int main()
{
    foo();
    return 0;
}
```

Compile lib with rustc:

```
rustc foo.rs
```

Compile binary and link with library:

```
gcc -g bar.c libfoo.a -ldl -lpthread -lrt -lgcc_s -lpthread -lc -lm -o bar
```

Run inside debugger:

```
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/kykc/rusttest/bar 
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff72117df in __cxa_thread_atexit_impl (func=<optimized out>, obj=<optimized out>, dso_symbol=0x0) at cxa_thread_atexit_impl.c:67
67  cxa_thread_atexit_impl.c: No such file or directory.
```

gcc:

```
gcc-4.8.real (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2
```

rustc:

```
rustc 1.0.0-beta (9854143cb 2015-04-02) (built 2015-04-02)
```

It works completely fine with dylib. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try turning optimizations off

Comment: `rustc -g -C opt_level=0 foo.rs`
`gcc -O0 -g bar.c libfoo.a -ldl -lpthread -lrt -lgcc_s -lpthread -lc -lm -o bar`
produces same result

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that thread-locals with destructors can only be used in position-independent executables (due to [a bug](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/24445)) . Fix: pass the `-pie` flag to gcc, or wait a day or two.

This is caused by [`std::io::stdio::_print`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/16e1fcead14628701e1b10b9d00c898d748db2ed/src/libstd/io/stdio.rs#L402-L414) and [`std::io::stdio::LOCAL_STDOUT`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/16e1fcead14628701e1b10b9d00c898d748db2ed/src/libstd/io/stdio.rs#L24-L28) in the standard library:

```
/// Stdout used by print! and println! macros
thread_local! {
    static LOCAL_STDOUT: RefCell<Option<Box<Write + Send>>> = {
        RefCell::new(None)
    }
}

// ...

pub fn _print(args: fmt::Arguments) {
    let result = LOCAL_STDOUT.with(|s| {
        if s.borrow_state() == BorrowState::Unused {
            if let Some(w) = s.borrow_mut().as_mut() {
                return w.write_fmt(args);
            }
        }
        stdout().write_fmt(args)
    });
    if let Err(e) = result {
        panic!("failed printing to stdout: {}", e);
    }
}
```

The `Box` in `LOCAL_STDOUT` has the destructor in that case, so the executable crashes when the thread-local variable is touched. I've filed [#24445](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/24445), and Alex Crichton has [diagnosed and fixed the underlying cause](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/24445) already.

Printing doesn't require initialising the threads or anything; there's fallback to `stdout()` in the case that `LOCAL_STDOUT` contains `None` (which is the default). Just passing `-pie` is enough to convince the executable to print `bork!` instead of crashing.